# Converting Silverlight browser app to windows phone app

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I am using the code http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prvn_131971/3285/

i want to convert it to windows phone app. The only problem i am facing is that the alphabets and words to be guessed are not coming to right places... I have tried alot... but I just cant move the positions of the grid and the stackpanel from the top of the app... Please help!

here is the code.

```
namespace Canhangman
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public int x = 0;
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
    StackPanel sp_special = new StackPanel();
    List<TextBox> text = new List<TextBox>(); // keeping all textboxes
    StackPanel sp1;
    Grid g, g1;
    Rectangle r1;
    int nooftxtbox = -1;
    string[] words = new string[100] {"KARAKARTAL","BİLGİSAYAR","KİTAPLIK","FAALİYET","PANTOLON",
                                     "KİLİSE","TELEFON","CEYLAN","KANGURU","JANDARMA","PİYADE","MAKARNA",
                                     "KEVGİR","MALUMAT","GALERİ","ARABA","DİKELMEK","KALKMAK","OTURMAK",
                                     "GÖZLÜKÇÜ","DOĞUŞTAN","YAZICI","TARAYICI","ŞİFONYER","FASULYE","PAZARLIK",
                                     "KALDIRIM","İNDİRİM","SAĞANAK","ABAJUR","KARNIBAHAR","ÜNİFORMA","ÜNİVERSİTE",
                                     "AYAKLANMA","TEBESSÜM","MÜTEAHHİT","MÜBAŞİR","MÜSTEŞAR","MÜFETTİŞ","BAKANLIK",
                                     "CUMHURİYET","OSMANLI","PAŞAZADE","KUMBURGAZ","PANSİYON","TANSİYON","İLKOKUL",
                                     "KONSERVATUAR","KONGRE","KUMANDA","KEMER","ÇAKMAK","ÇAYDANLIK","CETVEL","BİSTÜYER",
                                     "KELEBEK","KAPLUMBAĞA","KORTEJ","TUHAF","BORNOZ","KAPŞON","OROTORYO","ORDİNARYÜS",
                                     "KERPİÇ","KALPAZAN","TASARRUF","MÜNECCİM","İLMİHAL","MUHBİR","LİZOZOM","RİBOZOM",
                                     "KLASÖR","KILAVUZ","MODÜLER","TEHLİKE","STATİK","MEKANİK","POTANSİYEL","KULAKLIK",
                                     "ARDIŞIK","ÇERÇEVE","MONİTÖR","SANDALYE","MERDİVEN","OTOBÜS","MİNİBÜS","KAREOKE",
                                     "KARTONPİYER","ÇEKMECE","ALIŞVERİŞ","KALDIRAÇ","KARINCA","KARBONAT","GERGEDAN",
                                     "İSTİRİDYE","TENEFFÜS","ORİGAMİ","BEZİK","EKONOMİ","GRAFİK"};
    public string s;

    public MainPage()
    {
        string[] alph = new string[29] {"A","B","C","Ç","D","E","F","G","Ğ","H","I","İ","J","K","L",
                                        "M","N","O","Ö","P","R","S","Ş","T","U","Ü","V","Y","Z"};

        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();

        SolidColorBrush sb = new SolidColorBrush();
        sb.Color = Colors.Blue;

        sp.Height = 100;
        sp_special.Height = 100;

        sp.Background = sb;
        sp_special.Background = sb;
        sp.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
        sp_special.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
        Canvas.SetLeft(sp, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(sp_special,0);
        Canvas.SetTop(sp,0);
        Canvas.SetTop(sp_special,200);
        sp1 = new StackPanel();
        sp1.Background = sb;
        sp1.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
        Canvas.SetLeft(sp1, 20);
        Canvas.SetTop(sp1, 100);
        g = new Grid();
        Canvas.SetLeft(g, 200);
        Canvas.SetTop(g, 320);
        g1 = new Grid();
        g.Height = 20;
        g1.Height= 20;          
        g.Width = 300;
        g1.Width =300;

        Canvas.SetLeft(g1, 200);
        Canvas.SetTop(g1, 300);
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(sp);
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(sp_special);
        ContentPanel.Children.Add(g);

        ContentPanel.Children.Add(g1);

        for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Name = "b" + i;
            b.Content = alph[i];
            b.Width = 25;
            b.Height = 5;
            b.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            if(i<20)
            {
                sp.Children.Add(b);
                b.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(b_Click);
            }
            else
            {
                sp_special.Children.Add(b);
                b.Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(b_Click);
            }
        }

        Random r = new Random();
        s = words[r.Next(0, words.Length)];
        for (int j = 0; j < s.Length; j++)
        {
            r1 = new Rectangle();
            r1.Width = 15;
            r1.Height = 5;
            SolidColorBrush sb1 = new SolidColorBrush();
            sb1.Color = Colors.Black;
            r1.Fill = sb1;
            TextBox t = new TextBox();
            t.Name = "t" + j;
            t.Text = s[j].ToString().ToUpper();
            t.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            t.Width = 25;
            t.Height = 5;
            t.IsEnabled = false;
            text.Add(t); // adding textBox to list
            g.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength((double)30) });
            g1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength((double)30) });
            g1.ShowGridLines = true;
            Grid.SetColumn(t, j);
            Grid.SetColumn(r1, j);
            if (t.Text != " ")
            {
                g.Children.Add(r1);
                g1.Children.Add(t);
            }
            nooftxtbox++;               
        }
    }

    private void b_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        bool iscomplete = true;
        bool flag = false;
        string bstr;
        TextBox txtName;
        bstr = ((Button)sender).Content.ToString();

        if (x != 6)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= nooftxtbox; j++)
            {
                txtName = g1.Children[j] as TextBox;
                if (txtName.Text == bstr)
                {
                    txtName.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j);
                    txtName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    txtName.IsEnabled = false;
                    ((Button)sender).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    flag = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ((Button)sender).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            if (!flag)
            {
                x = x + 1;
            }
            if (x == 1)
            {
                loop1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                head.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            if (x == 2)
            {
                loop1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                head.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                body1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            if (x == 3)
            {
                loop1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                head.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                body1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                lefthand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            if (x == 4)
            {
                loop1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                head.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                body1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                lefthand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                righthand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            if (x == 5)
            {
                loop1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                head.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                body1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                lefthand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                righthand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                leftleg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            if (x == 6)
            {
                loop1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                head.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                body1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                lefthand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                righthand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                leftleg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                rightleg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                deadtxt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                trybutton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                for (int i = 0; i < text.Count; i++)// checking whether user has completed the guess or not
                {
                    text[i].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                iscomplete = false;
                sp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                sp_special.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            if(iscomplete)
            {
                bool complete = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < text.Count; i++)// checking whether user has completed the guess or not
                {
                    if (text[i].Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                    {
                        complete = false;
                    }
                }

                if (complete)
                {
                    // safetxt and hiding the letter boxes
                    safetxt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    trybutton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    sp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    sp_special.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                    loop1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                    //hiding the hanged man
                    head.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    body1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    leftleg.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    rightleg.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    lefthand.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    righthand.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                    //showing man walking away
                    head_Copy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    body1_Copy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    leftleg_Copy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    rightleg_Copy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    lefthand_Copy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    righthand_Copy.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            deadtxt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            loop1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            head.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            body1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            leftleg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            rightleg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            lefthand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            righthand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            trybutton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
    private void trybutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ContentPanel.Children.Add(new MainPage());
    }    
}
}
```

this is the link of originial app that i want to change

the problem is at the dashes and the letters

http://www.sarayyayin.com/silverlighthangman/TestPage.html

I cant post images otherwise i would have uploaded the screenshot of my app :-(

Comment: Can you please show the specific code you're having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just convert a Silverlight 4 application into a Windows Phone 7 application.

They both use different version of Silverlight and are on completely different platforms using different set of controls.

Try building it step by step and reuse any code that you can out of existing application.

Comment: Yes I have done that... I changed that code to windows form step by step... the only problem is that the grid & stackpanels created in control stretches upto the whole screen and the buttons are not added in the stackpanel.

Comment: ok I have controlled the heights using the .height properties but the grids and stackpanels are created on the same centre of the canvas.

the canvas.settop and canvas.setleft properties dont seem to have any effect.. no matter what value i enter as points :-(

Comment: Can you post some code that can be helpful to recreate your problem?